# Making text static from within draw() function

Tags: processing

I pulled the below example from a tutorial I found because it contains most of the basic functionality that I'm looking for. My trouble is this: I want each string from the headline[] array would move onto the window (as it already does) and then STOP right before exiting. Rather than disappear, I want the string to remain static as the next ones from the array moves in ... before also eventually stopping. In other words, I want the text to appear as if it's piling on top of each other as more strings enter the window.

Here is the code:

```
String[] headlines = {
  "Processing downloads break downloading record.", 
  "New study shows computer programming lowers cholesterol.",
};

PFont f; 
float x; 
int index = 0;

void setup() {
  size(400, 200);
  f = createFont("Arial", 16, true);

  x = width;
}

void draw() {

  background(255);
  fill(0);

  textFont(f, 16);
  textAlign (LEFT);


  text(headlines[index], x, 180); 

  x = x - 5.5;

  float w = textWidth(headlines[index]); 


  if (x < 2) {
    x = width;
    index = (index + 1) % headlines.length;
  }
}
```

Comment: You might want to add a tag to show the language this is written in...

Comment: Try to limit the change in the x value, i.e. `if(x > 100) x = x - 5.5;` or something like that.

Answer (score 0):

As I've understood your question you want the text written to the screen to pile up, meaning that they are not redrawn each time the draw() function is ran.

Move the background() call from the draw() function to the setup() function.

Background() will redraw the background, and clear away the text from the last run of draw(). If you want to keep what's drawn to the canvas during draw()'s last round, just simply move the call of background() to the setup() function.

[Processing background() function documentation](http://processing.org/reference/background_.html)

Comment: I need the background() function to be in draw(), otherwise the text will not be legible as moves across the window. I only want the text to begin 'piling up' after it has reached its stopped point at the margins of the window..... is that possible?

Comment: OK, so if I have understood you correctly you want: once the program has reached the end, you want to display all the iterations the text has been trough (that the text is piled up?)? Create a flag for redraw background, move the background() into a if-branch on this flag, then once it reach the end, set the flag to false? Would that work?